# recursion in scheme: base cases and unexpected errors

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm a scheme noob, teaching myself scheme as a way of getting a deeper understanding of functional style and technique.  I've run into a problem with recursion and base cases.

Sometimes I will get an unexpected error when the recursion hits the base case:

```
ERROR: In procedure #<unspecified>:
ERROR: Wrong type to apply: #<unspecified>
```

I've played with different ways of expressing the base case.  I've discovered enough working patterns that I can always come up with an incantation that will behave as I intend.  But I don't really understand why some of the following examples fail and some succeed.

```
(define (pt t)
   (display t)
   (if (> t 0)
       (pt (- t 1))))

;;good
(define (pt t)
   (if (> t 0)
       ((display t)
    (pt (- t 1)))))

;;bad
(define (pt t)
   (if (> t 0)
       (pt (- t 1)))
   (display t))

;;good
(define (pt t)
   (if (> t 0)
       (pt (- t 1))))

;;bad
(define (pt t)
   (if (> t 0)
       ((pt (- t 1)))))

;;good
(define (pt t)
   (define (qt t)
      (display t)
      (pt (- t 1)))
   (if (> t 0)
       (qt t)))
```

These are all toy procedures to help me understand the recursion mechanism.  I'd like to understand why the procedures labeled `;;bad` toss an error.

I suspect the problem is related to the fact the (if) is not a procedure.  If anyone can get me pointed in the right direction, I'd be grateful.

The scheme that I'm using is guile 2.0.11

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what arguments you call the procedure with in order to obtain the error?

Comment: When you see `((pt ...` you better make sure the proc is indeed returning a proc.

Answer (score 2):

One by one:

```
(define (pt t)
   (display t)
   (if (> t 0)
       (pt (- t 1))))
```

means, display the received argument value, and then, if it's > 0, decrease it by 1 and repeat; else do nothing. So it's good, it's even tail-recursive; given a number it'll print (though without any spacing) all the decreasing numbers until it hits 0.

But since there's no alternative clause in the `if` form, there's no value to return in the end. In such cases the returned value is "unspecified" by the standard. It's not neat to cause it to be returned; here we see it returned after all the numbers are printed. But that in itself is not an error, only trying to use such a value is an error.

```
;;good
(define (pt t)
   (if (> t 0)
       ((display t)
    (pt (- t 1)))))
```

here indentation is misleading; `((display t) (pt (- t 1)))` means, display `t`, then call its result (which is undefined) as if it were a function (which it ain't). BAD. (e.g.) MIT Scheme says: `;The object #[unspecified-return-value] is not applicable.` - after printing `1` first.

Why? Because to find out the return value of `(display t)` it must first execute it. But why 1 and not 5 (when testing `(pt 5)`)? Because to evaluate `(f x)` Scheme must find out the values of both `f` and `x` first, and it does so in some unspecified order.

MIT Scheme (e.g.) evaluates (tries to find the values of) the arguments before evaluating the function; thus `(pt (- t 1))` is entered first which leads us to the base case first (in the non-tail-recursive manner, since we've yet to call `display` etc): again the alternative-less `if` is entered, `(if (> 0 0) ((display 0) (pt (- 0 1))))`, at which point the absence of the alternative clause causes the `if` form to return the "unspecified value", again (which causes an error when this value is used).

```
;;bad
(define (pt t)
   (if (> t 0)
       (pt (- t 1)))
   (display t))
```

good, actually: first counts down to 0 from a number `t`, then prints them all on its way back up from the recursion, i.e. prints an increasing sequence from `0` to `t`. Not tail-recursive.

```
;;good
(define (pt t)
   (if (> t 0)
       (pt (- t 1))))
```

does nothing, while counting down to 0 (when given a number), where it just terminates. Tail recursive.

```
;;bad
(define (pt t)
   (if (> t 0)
       ((pt (- t 1)))))
```

indeed bad; tries to call the result of `(pt (- t 1))` (thus not tail-recursive), but this result isn't a function: after counting down to 0, the `if` is missing the alternative so returns, again, an unspecified value. MIT Scheme says: `;The object #[unspecified-return-value] is not applicable.` (guile should say something similar; please *do always include concrete tests and full error messages* with your SO questions).

The last one

```
(define (pt t)
   (define (qt t)
      (display t)
      (pt (- t 1)))
   (if (> t 0)
       (qt t)))
```

does not define `qt` on each invocation; it is defined only once, as internal procedure to `pt` when that is defined, so you can just inline it:

```
(define (pt t)
   (if (> t 0)
       (begin (display t)
              (pt (- t 1)))))
```

this again prints all the descending numbers, but it doesn't print 0.

Your main lesson here is always to include the alternative clause in the `if` form, together with the test and the consequent. And, don't use misleading indentation.

If you have specific questions about any of these snippets, please ask a new, separate question for each code fragment.

Comment: Thanks, you've cleared up my question.  I was blind because I was still thinking of (if) 'falling thru' as it would in a procedural language.

Comment: @ClaudeGWilbur but this *is* a procedural language, and its `if` *will* fall through, if there is something to fall through *to* (i.e. when `if` is not a last expression). It's better if you post a separate question on SO about one separate code snippet, for clarifications. That way there's less chance for misunderstanding. (also, do accept an answer that is "most helpful among the answers", if there is one :) ).